# Can't uninstall Vmware player 4.0.3

Tags: kernel, vmware

I have vmware palyer 4.0.3 installed on ubuntu 12.04 with kernel 3.3.6.

For some reasons the network doesn't work on it ( maybe because of the kernel) 
I tried to uninstall the vmware player using wmware-installer -u vmware-player but it failed.

This is what I get in the dialog:

```
The vmware installer could not shut down all running virtual machines. if you have ACE VMs open, please shut them down or suspend them now and press 'Retry' to continue.
```

I don't have any vm running and I tried to use serive command to stop but it failed again with this error:

```
bamdad@laptop:~/Software/patch$ sudo service vmware stop
Stopping VMware services:
VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
/etc/init.d/vmware: line 351: [: 16519574018620477093: integer expression expected
VM communication interface socket family                           failed
Virtual machine communication interface                            failed
Virtual machine monitor                                            failed
Blocking file system                                                done
ERROR: Module vmnet is in use by [permanent]
```

I searched for custom patches and found nothing.
I have no idea what else I can do to uninstall this vmware and install another one.

Please help

Bamdad

Comment: Have you tried this procedure from the [VMware KB](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=38) for manually uninstalling it?

Comment: @MartyFried i tried but I can't stop the service using /etc/init.d/vmware stop

Comment: @MartyFried same result

Comment: @MartyFried The instructions say to use `sudo su -`, which is *not* the same as `sudo su`. `sudo su -` is essentially equivalent to `sudo -i`, whereas `sudo su` is essentially equivalent to `sudo -s`. **It would be worth trying `sudo su -` or `sudo -i`.** (See [`man sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/sudo.8.html) and [`man su`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/su.1.html) for details.)

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't figure out what was still running, my solution was taken from the [VM Knowledge Base](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=38).

From the Section 6 "Remove the VMware startup scripts" we know where all startup scripts are located. Simply **remove** them all, and then **restart** your machine. On my Ubuntu box it was `# rm /etc/rc{2,3,4,5}.d/*vmware*`. Nothing related to VMWarewill be running.

After that I was able to run `vmware-installer --uninstall-product vmware-workstation`. Or enter whatever you're going to uninstall.

This solution isn't a clean one, but it worked for me. It simply lasted to long to figure out which process was using kernel modules or which files where still open.

Comment: +1 This also works for VMware Workstation 9